# Coloring a circular disc

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

A circular disc is divided into exactly 5 sectors and the angles subtended by the sectors are 70, 71, 72, 73 and 74 degrees.  The sectors are to be painted using at most three colours - Red, Blue and Green - such that no two adjacent sectors are painted in the same colour.  In how many ways can the disc be painted ?

---

My attempt :-

All the sectors are distinct since they subtend different angles , so we can start by colouring any one of them, the first sector selected randomly will have 3 choices among R, B and G.  Now the sector adjacent to it will have 2 colors, similarly the 3rd sector and the 4th sector will also have 2 colours that can be used to paint it.  Now the 5th sector can be tricky since if the colour of 1st and 4th sector is the same, there will be 2 choices for the 5th sector whereas if the 1st and 4th sector are of different colours then the fifth sector should have only one colour option and that will be different from both 1st and the 4th sector.

I have assumed 1st, 2nd, 3rd .... sectors in an a clockwise-fashion.

so the result I am getting is $(3*2*2*2*2)$ + $(3*2*2*2*1)$ = $72$ ways which is not the correct answer.  Please help me where am I making the mistake in logic and how to solve it correctly

PS:- There are solutions available for similar question on the platform but they are using recursion logic which I am not aware of , so please help me with some alternative approach

Comment: Are the five pie wedges in fixed positions that are arranged radially in order by area?

Comment: I have posted an answer. You should be able to pinpoint the error in logic you were making.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum , yes the pie wedges are in fixed positions as per the solution provided by the author in my textbook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a *marked* clockwise order of sectors $70^\circ,71^\circ, 72^\circ,73^\circ,74^\circ$
$\small\text{list valid sequences of $A,B,C$ in lexicographic (dictionary) order}$

$ABABC\; ABACB\; ABCAB\; ABCAC\; ABCBC$

$ACABC\; ACACB\; ACBAB\;ACBAC\;ACBCB$

The first color alloted completely determines the possible sequences, hence the final answer $=3*10=30$

Comment: thank you @true blue anil, I believe the fault in my logic is that rather than the generalised PnC approach of 3*2*2... types, one needs to list down all the cases to solve.  The numbers of sectors are less, so listing all the ten cases was smooth, but I think it would get messy with more sectors introuduced as thenlisting all cases would be cumbersome

Comment: just an additional question popped into my head, what if all the sectors subtended equal angles (6 sectors of 60 degrees each), should the answer be 10 in that case ?

Comment: The question with equal sectors is whether the sectors are numbered (labeled) or not. If labeled, the answer would remain unchanged; but if unlabeled,  the answer would become just $20$ (i.e. we wouldn't multiply by $3!$)

Comment: why 20 ? aren't we are doing 3! * 10 , so why shouldnt it be 10 ?

Comment: Yes, $20$ was a typo !

Comment: I just saw the official answer given and its 30 , not 60

Comment: I have reconsidered the logic and amended: $30$ is correct !

Answer (score 1):

$3$ sectors & $2$ colors  (red-R, green-G)

1st sector, 2 choices

2nd sector, 1 choice

3rd sector, 1 choice

Total permutations  = $2 \times 1 \times 1 = 2$

RGR, GRG.

What "fault" in your logic?

Unless ... in a circle RGR = GRG