# Colouring a disc with sectors of equal areas

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

A circular disc is divided into exactly 6 sectors and the angle subtended by each sector is 60 degrees. The sectors are then to be painted using at most three colours - Red, Blue and Green - such that no two adjacent sectors are painted in the same colour. In how many ways can the disc be painted ?

---

Similar problem :- [Coloring a circular disc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4800048/coloring-a-circular-disc)

---

My attempt :-

Following the approach used in the similar problem asked earlier, I listed down all the cases and got the total answer has 22, however the official answer is 14.  I can't figure out where am I overcounting. Also, please suggest if there is any efficient approach involving combinatorics.

[image]

Comment: I suggest the mutually exclusive cases [x,y,z] where $~x,y,z \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}},~$ $~x \geq y \geq z,~$ and $~x + y + z = 6.~$  Then, manually attack each case.

Comment: As it’s stated, the question is not completely unambiguous. Are the disk and its constituent sections painted on both sides or only on one face? If the former, then you’ll have symmetries by flipping the disk over. That the answer is given as 14 settles the matter, but it remains for you to work out. When such flipping is  affirmatively allowed, such problems are often expressed in terms of stringing colored beads to create necklaces.

Comment: HINT: Denoting the number of sections of each color as $r$, $g$, and $b$, you know that $r+g+b=6$. And the color-adjacency constraint also gives you an upper bound on each of $r$, $g$, and $b$.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum is there any case from the ones I have listed in which there is a potential of flipping over resulting in the same case ?  I believe all the cases are unique in nature

Comment: Your sixth line, ```Red-Blue-Green-Red-Red-Green```, is not valid. Your eighth line, ```Red-Green-Blue-Red-Blue-Green```, is a rotation of the first line. Your third and fourth lines are likewise equivalent.

Comment: Thank you @DanielMathias for pointing out the rotation idea !